# WPF textblock resize dependant on max width and split

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Hello I have a textblock within a grid row. The text outside the width of the row is not shown. How can i split the text and display it underneath?

```
       //Actual -->
       //Date: 06/06/2018 realy long text is displayed, b

       //Wanted --> 

       //Date: 06/06/2018 realy long text is displayed, 
             //but not showing everything due to width
             //isue

Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();

DynamicGrid.Width = 450;
DynamicGrid.Height = 1000;
DynamicGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
DynamicGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
DynamicGrid.ShowGridLines = false;

RowDefinition gridRow;
gridRow = new RowDefinition();
gridRow.Height = new GridLength(50);
DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow);

TextBlock txtBlock1 = new TextBlock();
txtBlock1.Text = "06/06/2018 realy long text is displayed, but not showing everything due to width isue";
txtBlock1.FontSize = 20;
txtBlock1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
Grid.SetRow(txtBlock1, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(txtBlock1, 0);
DynamicGrid.Children.Add(txtBlock1);
```

Comment: Can you set `TextWrapping` property of Textblock to `true` and see what happens.

Comment: As simple as that it was.. txtBlock1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap; seeled the deal. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Glad it helped you. I will add the suggestion as answer to your question, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `TextWrapping` property of the `TextBlock` to `wrap` will cause the textblock to show full text.